# Angular Http Request - Getting data

Tags: angular, http

I'm trying to make user logging service but I've got some problems with data parsing, when user click on login button http request is called to api server, if username and password are correct server respond with user information and I need to parse this information to User variable and if user isn't null return true else returns false, but metod always returns true...

User service with method:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { User } from '../entities/User';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private usersUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/api/users';

  user: User;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.user != null;
  }

  isAdmin() {
    return this.user.isAdmin;
  }

  unLoggin() {
    this.user = null;
  }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.get<User>(`${this.usersUrl}/verify?username=${username}&password=${password}`)
      .map(
        user => {
          this.user = user;
          return this.user != null;
        });
  }

}
```

User example in json:

```
{"id":2,"name":"Some","email":"sometni","username":"iafouafa","password":"Hoifhnaol"}
```

I think there is multiple problems, first is the method is void, this I can solve, but if I remake it to returning boolean and put return statement at the end not to the map operator it will always return false... If you need more info, tell me what you need.

Sorry for my bad english.

Thank for any help !

Comment: Have you ever called the login method ? FYI : When using angular HttpClient return an observable (cf RXJS docs), if you want your request to be perform, you need to subscribe to it :`this.login.subscribe(data => {
      console.log("User Login: " + data)
    });`

Comment: If I remove map method and use your code it will log to the console json string with user information so username and password are correct, bud if I use `data => {this.user = data}` and `return this.user != null` it returns false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.get<User>(`${this.usersUrl}/verify?username=${username}&password=${password}`)
      .map(
        user => {
          return user;
        });
  }
```

now perform the login 
performe logging somewhere

```
this.login(username,pass).subascribe(user => {
       this.user = user;
     }
```

now you can call your isLoggedIn() method